# Task.Run invoking an EventHandler. Is it correct?

Tags: c#, async-await, task, eventhandler

I am writing unit tests for an async method and I think I should avoid .Invoke inside Task.Run in the next function.

Here is the current code under test:

```
public class Foo
{
  public event EventHandler<bool> Disconnect;

  { ... }

  public async Task ProcessNotification(bool e)
  {
    await Task.Run(() => Disconnect?.Invoke(this, e)).ConfigureAwait(false);
  }
}
```

Should I change it to this?:

```
public class Foo
{
  public event EventHandler<bool> Disconnect;

  { ... }

  public void ProcessNotification(bool e)
  {
    Disconnect?.Invoke(this, e));
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this the code under test or (part of) the test code?

Comment: This is the code under test. I would like to change it before writing the test if that is the case

Comment: If its not in an interface and be programmed that way to fit the definition of the interface even it its not relevant in this implementation then yes you should presumably change it.

Comment: Any particular reason for using Task.Run() ? Your first implementation basically starts a new thread and then waits for it to complete, which is meaningless, if you are not on a UI thread for example. If however this is UI thread and Disconnect is slow operation, you should invoke it on separate thread as in your first example, to prevent UI block.

Comment: Why `ConfigureAwait(false) `?

Comment: @PauloMorgado await + ConfigureAwait(false) are good friends

Comment: Using `ConfigureAwait(false)` everywhere as a rule can get you into trouble. I wrote about the reasons why here: [Don't use ConfigureAwait(false)](https://www.gabescode.com/dotnet/2022/02/04/dont-use-configureawait.html)

Comment: [ConfigureAwait FAQ](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/)

Comment: @HenkHolterman ProcessNotification() is simplified for the question. In the original code, it manages the notificacions and call the related event by using Task.Run() as you see in the first class.

Answer (score 0):

In general using `Task.Run` in the method implementation is a code smell, as written by async guru Stephen Cleary:

> do not use `Task.Run` in the implementation of the method; instead, use `Task.Run` to call the method.

- [`Task.Run` Etiquette and Proper Usage](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html)
- [`Task.Run` Etiquette Examples: Don't Use `Task.Run` in the Implementation](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html)